# Hansontable and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, handsontable

I'm totally new to Handsontable and I want to use it in my Nodejs&React app to save data in a Postgresql database.

Basically, I've tried to render the table component and its custom headers but I can't see how it can be used in with Nodejs, despite all the Googling I did.

**My current table on a page**
[image]

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

step1. Use a hands-on table to have the user fill in the data and when they press the save button, use "getSourceData" or "getData" to
Obtain table data.

step2. Submit the data acquired in step1 to the nodejs server and save the data to the Postgresql database.

I think this will make it possible.